# Do I need to resign to ask for a Letter of Recommendation?

Tags: resignation, masters

Is it possible to ask for LOR in December and resign in February?
I am applying for Masters and I need to attach 2 LOR's to submit my university application. But the notice period in my company is 6 months. It is a European company and I work remotely from India.
Application deadline is first week of Jan 2024
I would like to work in the company until July 2024.
When should I submit my resignation?
My work is greatly appreciated in my company and I'm certain that I will be provided with a good recommendation.

Comment: Depends on your relationship with the people you're asking, in my culture.

Answer (score 8):

You can ask for a recommendation letter at any time during or after working somewhere. The only real issue is it lets them know you're contemplating or already involved with a job search.

One young lady I worked with asked me for a recommendation every 2 years when her contract was close to expiring.

Comment: This particular letter of resignation has nothing to do with a job search

Comment: @XavierJ it doesn't matter, that is one of the implications of asking for one. The lady who asked me every 2 years wasn't job searching either, she renewed her contract every time.

Comment: If you specifically say, "it's for my master's program" then there is no way for anyone to infer that the letter is for finding a new job.  Especially if it's addressed to someone at a school, and the writer is specifically asked to suggest suitability for an education program.

Comment: @XavierJ you can say it's for a space shuttle ticket if you want. The implication is always going to be that they might be job searching.

Answer (score 3):

You have stated that the notice period is six months, so your timeline is already set.  Exactly how your employer will react is difficult to predict.

If, as you say, your work is appreciated, and you have a good relationship with the company, I would expect most people would be happy to give you a recommendation to help you move forward with your life and career.